# Show value of an input form from a page into another page with pure Javascript

Tags: javascript, forms, local-storage

I have two different pages. In the first one I have a form with name and email, and the second page should be the result page, and I want to show dynamically the name and email of the user from the form of the first page in the second page, and I precise, I want all this in pure javascript, not php. I tried the localStorage method, and this is what I got so far:

First page: [Form page](https://jsfiddle.net/74fxvzap/1/)

HTML:

```
<label>Name:</label>
<input type="text" id="name" />
<label>Email</label>
<input type="text" id="email" />
<button  onclick="testVariable()">Submit</button> <br />
```

Javascript

```
function testVariable() {
            var strText = document.getElementById("name").value;          
            var strText1 = document.getElementById("email").value;
            var result = strText + ' ' + strText1;
            if (typeof(Storage) !== "undefined") {
    // Store
            localStorage.setItem("programX").textContent = result;
             
        }
        }
```

Second page:[Result page](https://jsfiddle.net/u8Lzy6xj/)

HTML:

```
 <p>Hi 
<span id="result"></span> thank you for subscribing to our service
</p>
```

Javascript:

```
    // Check browser support
if (typeof(Storage) !== "undefined") {
// Retrieve
document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = localStorage.getItem("programX");
} else {
document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = "Browser does not support Web Storage.";
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[localStorage](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage) does not have any `textContent` property.

To set a `localStorage`

```
localStorage.setItem('key', 'value');
```

To get a `localStorage` value

```
localStorage.getItem('key');
```

So, what you are doing to **set** `localStorage` is **wrong**.

Replace

`localStorage.setItem("programX").textContent = result;`

with

`localStorage.setItem("programX", result);`